# eclipse-plugins in java perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have developed a plugin in eclipse that adds an option when user right clicks on a file.  But it shows up only in java perspective and not any in other. Can anyone please tell me the reason?

Here is my plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
            <command commandId="plugin.showDifferences" label="Show Differences" style="push">
                <activeWhen>
                    <iterate>
                        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java"/>
                        </adapt>
                    </iterate>
                </activeWhen>
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command defaultHandler="plugin_demo.Differences" id="plugin.showDifferences" name="Differences" />
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the Java perspective's Package Explorer view is a different beast than the Project Explorer view that appears in the other perspectives. If you want your right-click option to appear in both views, you'll have to add another `<menuContribution>` that contributes it to the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer` view. Something like this:

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
    <command commandId="plugin.showDifferences" label="Show Differences" style="push">
        <activeWhen>
            <iterate>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java"/>
                </adapt>
            </iterate>
        </activeWhen>
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```